# return thymeleaf template String add url parameter not work in spring boot with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, url, thymeleaf

I have a problem with the practice code .

It's fail with    formLogin?error

How can  i add error url parameter with formLogin page.

When only return formLogin, it's success.

my backend code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/formlogin")
    public String formLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        ..........

        return "formLogin";

    }//
    @GetMapping(value = "/formLoginPost")
    public String formLoginPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {



        //return "formLogin?error";
        return "redirect:formLogin?error";

    }
```

and with the formLogin page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorate="~{fragments/layout}">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content" th:remove="tag">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>Login page</h1>
            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <div th:if="${param.error}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        Invalid username or password.
                    </div>
                </div>
    .......
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: not map to formLogin?error in thymeleaf template

Answer (score 0):

seanwang. The correct way is using Spring-Security where you can declare successful and fail URLs for authentication form. And then you can make what you need in your controller with the specified URL. The Spring-Security add security filter and validators in your application. And when the user try authenticate, filter will check if the Principal is present in Session. If yes, the user will be redirected to the successful url, if not - to the fail URL.

Comment: does it can not no use spring security ?

Comment: i was mean that the thymeleaf can not map to formLogin?error